# How to select the latest record of each month?

Tags: sql, database, teradata, teradatasql, rdbms

I guess it is really hard to be friends with sql. Please help!
I have history table that contains master records of customer for 3 years.
the table looks like this:

Table A:

```
| ID  | Name | Number|Date(in Timestamp)|
|:--- |:----:|:-----:|-----------------:|
|123  | John | 101   |20210101 01:11:15 |
|123  | John | 102   |20210103 01:11:15 |
|123  | John | 103   |20210301 01:11:15 |
|123  | John | 104   |20210325 01:11:15 |
|123  | John | 105   |20210415 01:11:15 |
|123  | John | 106   |20210416 01:11:15 |
|124  | Mary | 201   |20210101 01:11:15 |
|124  | Mary | 202   |20210103 01:11:15 |
|124  | Mary | 203   |20210201 01:11:15 |
|124  | Mary | 204   |20210225 01:11:15 |
|124  | Mary | 204   |20210315 01:11:15 |
|124  | Mary | 205   |20210416 01:11:15 |
```

I need to know what are the records of each customers at the end of each month.

Expected result is:

```
| ID  | Name | Number|Date    |
|123  | John | 102   |20210131|
|123  | John | 104   |20210331|
|123  | John | 106   |20210430|
|124  | Mary | 202   |20210131|
|124  | Mary | 204   |20210228|
|124  | Mary | 204   |20210331|
|124  | Mary | 205   |20210430|
```

I created below sql but it looks like i cannot use substr for Timestamp.
Is there any other way to do this? will really appreciate any help!

```
select * from (select t1.id, t1.name, t1.number, t1.date,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by substr(date,1,6) order by date desc) as Rowrank
from tableA t1)sub where Rowrank = 1
```

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify the expected result.

Comment: @Jojo10478, please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Teradata, you might find `trunc()` to be a simple method:

```
select a.id, a.name, a.number, a.date
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by trunc(date, 'MON') order by date desc) as seqnum
      from tableA a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

Teradata also supports qualify:

```
select a.id, a.name, a.number, a.date
from tableA a
qualify row_number() over (partition by trunc(date, 'MON') order by date desc) = 1
```

Comment: You can also get rid of the subquery in Teradata with the `QUALIFY` clause `select * from tableA QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by trunc(date, 'MON') order by "date" desc)  = 1;`

Comment: Omg this is what I am looking for! I just had to add the "a.id" and trunc(date, 'YEAR') in the partition and voila! Now I can sleep well. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @JNevill , I tried to use the QUALIFY and it gave me the same results! I think I`ll be using it instead of the subquery. Thank you!

Comment: @Jojo10478: No need for adding `trunc(date, 'YEAR')`, MON truncates to the first of month. Btw, `last_day(date)` can also be used.

Comment: @dnoeth, you are right! the query gave me the same output without the `trunc(date, 'YEAR')`. About the `last_day(date)`, yes, I just discovered that I can use it to output the date for end of month. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Just when I thought I am already done with this problem, to my surprise I got additional question related to this topic. If you have some time, could you take a look on my latest post? I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: @Jojo10478 . . . If you have a new question, it should be asked as a *new* question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer:

Get the `Year` and `Month` values from the timestamp value and partition based on the `Id, year and Month`.

```
select * 
from (
    select t1.id, t1.name, t1.number, t1.date,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t1.id,YEAR(date_format(str_to_date(t1.date, '%Y%m%d'),'%Y-%m-%d')),MONTH(date_format(str_to_date(t1.date, '%Y%m%d'),'%Y-%m-%d')) order by date desc) as Rowrank
    from tableA t1
     )sub where Rowrank = 1
```

Comment: I am having syntax error between "," and "YEAR". for the line "ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t1.id,YEAR". I am afraid this syntax or format is not available for Teradata database.

Comment: Previously the tag was `mysql` and now you changed it to teradata. Please try to do the same pattern in teradata like convert the timestamp value to date and fetch `month` and `year`, then partition using the columns

Comment: yes, I am sorry that was my bad. I honestly just realized that mysql is another system. I will try to look for the same pattern in teradata. thanks so much!

Comment: This pattern gave me expected results in teradata. Thanks again for the idea!