# Defining Month Time Partition using Teradata Data Transfer Service Custom Schema

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-transfer

I am looking for a way to define a Teradata Data Transfer custom schema that implements a month based date partition.  The documentation only provides a method to do this at a `timestamp` or `date` level.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/teradata-migration-options#custom_schema_file

Is there an undocumented approach to defining a custom schema file that handles this? Or is the alternative to migrate at the day level, then once in BigQuery insert into a table that is defined with the month partition?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the  [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69044254/15774176)  :

> In Teradata, you might find trunc() to be a simple method:
>
> ```
> select a.id, a.name, a.number, a.date
> from (select a.*,
>              row_number() over (partition by trunc(date, 'MON') order by date desc) as seqnum
>       from tableA a
>      ) a
> where seqnum = 1;
> ```
>
> Teradata also supports qualify:
>
> ```
> select a.id, a.name, a.number, a.date
> from tableA a
> qualify row_number() over (partition by trunc(date, 'MON') order by date desc) = 1
> ```

As mentioned in the [Documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Database-SQL-Data-Definition-Language-Detailed-Topics/April-2018/CREATE-TABLE-Indexes/CREATE-TABLE-Index-Definition-Clause/Partitioning-Expression-Based-on-Updatable-Current-Date-and-Timestamp-Expressions), you can refer to the Explanation:

> A partitioned primary index enables Teradata Database to partition the
> rows of a table or uncompressed join index in such a way that row
> subsets can be accessed efficiently without resorting to full-table
> scans. If the partitioning expression is defined using an updatable
> current date or updatable current timestamp, the partition that
> contains the most recent rows can be defined to be as narrow as
> possible to optimize efficient access to those rows.

> **An additional
> benefit of an updatable current date or updatable current timestamp
> for a partitioning is that the partitioning expression can be designed
> in such a way that it might not need to be changed as a function of
> time.**

> you can specify the DATE, CURRENT_DATE, or
> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP functions in the partitioning expression of a table
> or uncompressed join index and then periodically update the resolution
> of their values. This enables rows to be repartitioned on the newly
> resolved values of the DATE, CURRENT_DATE, or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
> functions at any time you determine that they require reconciliation.
> You can update the resolution of your partitioning scheme by
> submitting appropriate ALTER TABLE TO CURRENT statements.

For more information, you can refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/dw2bq/d).

Comment: @Daniel Zagales Posted an answer, is it helpful?